# Waiting until message received from handler

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a handler in one class and when some message comes to that handler, i want to perform some operation in another class, but not before the message is received, how can i do that?

Comment: so notify "the other class" in your `Handler#dispatchMessage` method

Comment: I have tried setting  a boolean to true when the message is received in handler, and checking for the boolean status in another class, but since the message is received later, the boolean never returns false while in onCreate()  of another class. I want to wait there till the boolean changes its state.

Comment: @pskink can you please explain it a bit more clear?

Comment: did you override `dispatchMessage` ?

Comment: I am using handleMessage(), can you please explain how to use dispatch message with an example? It would be great..

Comment: ok you have `handleMessage`, so you know when `Message`s are handled, what else do you need?

Comment: Problem is not there, messages are handled properly. But when my other activity is loaded, till then the boolean is not set to true, so execution bypasses any further operation. After some time, i receive the message in handler and boolean is set to true, but check for it has already passed in the other activity.

Comment: i have no idea what boolean you are talking about, what EXACTLY do you want to achieve?

Comment: Assume 2 activities, activity A and B. I have a handler in activity A. Assume activity B is loading, i want boolean to be true to perform further operations in B, but boolean sets to true after some time when message is received in handler. During this, the check for boolean in B has already passed, now my question is how to wait for the boolean to change its state from handler so that i can perform further operations in B

Comment: then pass in "extras" a `Messenger` or `ResultReceiver`

Comment: @pskink Can you please explain it with a simple example?

Comment: did you pass a ResultReceiver in the Intent extras?

Comment: @pskink Nope, can you provide a sample?

Comment: i don't think so, whats is a problem with passing a variable in extras?